# Clicking on checkbox based on span value in WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I Would like to select the  the checkbox based on "Costco Wholesale Corporation" value in:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="" aria-describedby="entity-search-grid_selected">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" class="itmchk" value="110504">
</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="font-weight: bold;" title="Costco Wholesale Corporation" aria-describedby="entity-search-grid_name">
  <div class="tree-wrap tree-wrap-ltr" style="width:18px;">
    <div style="left:0px;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s tree-minus treeclick"></div>                                         
  </div>
  <span class="cell-wrapper">Costco Wholesale Corporation</span>
</td>
```

I have tried the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[span[text()='Costco Wholesale Corporation']]/preceding-sibling::td/input[@name='chkbox'"));
```

but getting following exception:

> invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //td[span[text()='Costco Wholesale Corporation']]/preceding-sibling::td/input[@name='chkbox' because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//td[span[text()='Costco Wholesale Corporation']]/preceding-sibling::td/input[@name='chkbox''

Could you help to write the xpath selector.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that xpath `td[span[text()` is definitely invalid. Remember that the `[...]` syntax is only for filters, not for defining the path. So it has to be:

```
//td/span[text...
```

Also since you select `span` first, you need to get back to `td` level and then choose a sibling:

```
//td/span[text()='Costco Wholesale Corporation']/../preceding-sibling::td/input[@name='chkbox']
```

Given your HTML, you could also simplify it to select `td` byt title and then its sibling:

```
//td[@title='Costco Wholesale Corporation']/preceding-sibling::td/input[@name='chkbox']
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you want to use xpath. The moment someone changes the structure of the site the whole selector will be worthless. I really recommend sticking to css selectors as long as you can. In this case it's just:

```
driver.findElement(By.css("input[name='chkbox'][value='110504']"));
```

And the main advantage of this approach is that only changes which directly concern the element will force you to change the selector.

Of course my selector might not be valid if there are some parts of site that you didn't show us and that may have inpact on selector. But even then I believe there is a way to use css to get to the element more directly.

Comment: In general I agree with you but in this case OP is looking for an element based on text contained in an element which a CSS selector cannot do. That value you use in the locator may be dynamic or require information ahead of time that OP doesn't have, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your provided `xPath` is syntactically incorrect.. try using below `xPath` :-

```
String xPath = "//span[text()='Costco Wholesale Corporation']/preceding::input[@name='chkbox']";

 driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
```

Hope it helps...:)